# How to make Bootstrap 3 modal display in front and not faded?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that does not appear well onclick. I have seen many fix on stackoverflow among which z-index but none of those worked for me.

This is a [fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kressly/79feLhek/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/kressly/79feLhek/16/)

This is my bootstrap modal code

Click here

```
<div class="modal fade" id="compose-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Compose New Message</h4>
                    </div>

                   <!-- <form action="#" method="post"> -->


                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                  Bla Bla Bla


                                </div>
                            </div>







                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer clearfix">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Send Message</button>
                        </div>

                   <!-- </form> -->


                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
```

**How to make Bootstrap 3 modal display in front and not faded like in the Fiddle ?**

Answer (score 1):

What version of JQuery did you used to run the code? I tried using JQuery 1.11 and 2 and it works. Try to change the JQuery version on your jsfiddle and see if it works for you